# C++ Unable to override virtual function

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
  class Service : public ::grpc::Service {
   public:
    Service();
    virtual ~Service();
    virtual ::grpc::Status ConnectGameServer(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<GameServerRequest>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<GameServerResponse>* response);
  };
```

And I have to override `ConnectGameServer`  so here is how I try it:

```
namespace Vibranium {
    class GameServerService final : public Vibranium::GameServer::Service{
        grpc::Status ConnectGameServer(grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<GameServerRequest>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<GameServerResponse>* response) override;
    };
}
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__ZN4grpc13ServerBuilder16AddListeningPortERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt10shared_ptrINS_17ServerCredentialsEEPi", referenced from:
      __ZN22GameAuthorativeManager15StartTestServerEv in GameAuthorativeManager.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [bin/WorldServer] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Source/WorldServer/CMakeFiles/WorldServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [WorldServer] Error 2
```

Why do I get this error? Where is my mistake and how can I fix it ?

Comment: The missing reference is to `_grpc::ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials>, int*)` - are you linking against the grpc runtime libraries?

Comment: @nanofarad this is what I have in my CMakeLists: `target_link_libraries(${AppName} PUBLIC Common asio gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc++_reflection)`

Comment: I build with bazel so I don't know the ins and outs of CMake, but that's worth editing into your post (cmake/grpc tags and title update may also be helpful in making this question visible to the right folks)

Comment: This is a linking error. You're not linking the other libraries correctly.